# Probability: student passing an exam by randomly guessing (no calculator)

Tags: probability

Assuming you can't use a calculator, how do you estimate the answer to the following problem?

Suppose an exam has 40 questions, all multiple choice. Each question has 5 choices and you need 20 correct answers to pass. You decided to randomly guess all the answers. What's the probability that you'll pass the exam?

Comment: Does the question ask you to numerically estimate the probability? Otherwise, you can express the answer as a summation of binomial probabilities.

Comment: *You decided to randomly guess all the answers.* - No, I didn't! What I did do was to check the answer that had most things in common with almost all others variants. And I passed! Both times! So the chances are pretty good, in fact! :-)

Comment: In what class is $20/40$ an adequate passing grade?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, will determine the use of the central limit theorem (using tables of the normal probability distribution - approximation to the binomial distribution Bin(n,p) = Bin(40,0.2) normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma)=N(n*p,\sqrt{np(1-p)}=N(40\cdot 0.2,\sqrt{40 \cdot 0.2 (1-0.2)}$).